# Issues installing psycopg2 in EC2 instance

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, psycopg2

I'v been trying to install the package [hgvs](http://hgvs.readthedocs.io/en/0.4.x/installation.html), which requires psycopg2 in order to work properly. The installation using pip runs smoothly until the following error occurs:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.a(fe-connect.o): unrecognized relocation (0x2a) in section `.text'

/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1


----------------------------------------
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-ubuntu/psycopg2/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-rh6BEQ-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-ubuntu/psycopg2
```

Similar errors were resolved by installing python-dev and libpq-dev, which already are on their newest versions (2.7.4 and 9.5.3). 
I don't know how much of an impact this plays, but upon running sudo apt-get install libpq-dev, I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libpq-dev is already the newest version (9.5.3-1).
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apt-utils : Depends: libdb5.3 but it is not installable
 libapt-pkg5.0 : Breaks: libapt-inst1.5 (< 0.9.9~) but 0.9.7.7ubuntu6 is to be installed
 libc-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.18) but 2.21-7 is to be installed
 libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.18) but 2.21-7 is to be installed
 libc6 : Breaks: libtirpc1 (< 0.2.3) but 0.2.2-5build1 is to be installed
         Breaks: locales (< 2.21) but 2.13+git20120306-9 is to be installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.17-0ubuntu5.1) but 2.21-7 is to be installed
 libpq-dev : Depends: libpq5 (= 9.5.3-1) but it is not installable
 libstdc++6 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.3.1-7) but it is not installable
          Breaks: python-scipy (<= 0.14.1-1) but 0.11.0+dfsg1-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
          Breaks: python3-scipy (<= 0.14.1-1) but 0.11.0+dfsg1-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
 E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Unfortunately the similar questions I've found have been responded with magical one-lines that solved the issues for some. None of those have worked, and much less served to explained the underlaying cause of the issue. If someone could help out that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use this following commands it will work

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
sudo apt-get install -y python3.4-dev
sudo apt-get install -y libpq-dev

pip3 install psycopg2
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install -y python3.4-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3.4-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.4-dev'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.4-dev'`

although python 3.3 is currently installed. The other commands return that my packages are all up to date, despite giving me similar warnings to the ones on my original question (2nd code block).

Comment: Change this "python3.4-dev" to "python3-dev"

Comment: `python3 is already the newest version (3.3.1-0ubuntu1).
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies: apt-utils : Depends: libdb5.3 but it is not installable
 libapt-pkg5.0 : Breaks: libapt-inst1.5 (< 0.9.9~) but 0.9.7.7ubuntu6 is to be installed
 libc-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.18) but 2.21-7 is to be installed`

should I try uninstalling and reinstalling such dependencies that are creating problems using `'apt-get -f install' ` ?

Comment: Yes I guess those dependancies are causing this issues.

Comment: I may have to create a new question for this, but how careful should I be to run the command, given this message: 
`WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
  apt libapt-pkg5.0 (due to apt) libstdc++6 (due to apt) libc-bin
8 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 256 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fuly instaled or rmvd. 
Need to get 3574kB of archives.
After this operation, 1565MB disk space will be free.
You are about to do something potentialy harmful.
To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'`